# Modelling a computer monitor - need some topology advice on using edge loops for sharpening

Tags: modeling, topology

I'm modelling a computer monitor (as a learning exercise after completing Blender Guru's "Donut" and "Anvil" tutorials) and need some advice on how to use edge loops the right way for sharpening some details. Please let me explain my problem with a few screenshots, see below.

The last screenshot shows the problem, the three edge loops over the corner surface causes problem when applying subsurface modifier.

I really like to learn the best way of working with topology, maybe someone can guide me in the right direction on how to model my example in a better way? My blend file is attached at the end.

Overview of model (using Mirror modifier):
[image: Overview of model (using Mirror modifier)]

Detail on my edge loops  for sharpening the corners:
[image: Detail on my edge loops for sharpening the corners]

Artifact visible using Matcap shading:
[image: Artifact visible using Matcap shading]

Blend file:
[image]

Comment: The artifact looks like the 3 vertices are not aligned (same height).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it seems a bit difficult to align them exactly and I would prefer a solution where I can modify my topology to be able to delete them (i.e. just to keep one edge going over the flat surface, but keeping the edges that sharpens the corner). Not sure how to approach that problem...

Comment: One not the best way is to go with edges in the corners continuing all over the surface, like [in this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4trou.jpg). Note that this is simple bevel of the corner edge made after dissolving 2 edge loops. What you saw was most likely due to too much tiny faces (made with Subsurf) in the corner of uneven surface. In this case change the flow of edges.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will try this as well as the suggestion in the answer by Dontwalk.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one possible solution. Model with quads for your front faces (Don't have an edge on the corner).

[image]

[image]

[image]